# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: in javascript using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, http, https, flask

I am trying to send a HTTP request in javascript using XMLHttpRequest and so I am using the following code in an HTML file. I have a server running which returns a dictionary of form `{'test' : 'string'}`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/test", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  xhr.send();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
  console.log(xhr.status)

  function processRequest(e)
  {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4)
    {
      alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  }
</script>
```

However in spite of adding the header, I am getting a Cross-Origin Request Blocked: error in my console when I try to print xhr.status in the console it shows 0 as response.
I am using flask server which shows a bad message error on using HTTPS, so I am using an HTTP request.

Comment: Is the page that this script is running on, also hosted on `http://localhost:5000/`?

Comment: No, Its a separate HTML file through which I want to send a HTTP request.

Comment: That is the problem, read about why it is blocked, maybe [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). You cannot set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the client side. This needs to be set up on the server, i.e. the server should allow you to connect to other domain(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not control CORS from front end. You have to put the CORS module to your back end server.

check the link [flask cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).